# How to insert byte[] array with ORMlite into image column

Tags: c#, sql-server, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

A subtask of my webservice is to save a file (along with some meta data) in a database.
The webservice is based on [ServiceStack](http://servicestack.net) and its version of [ORMlite](http://www.servicestack.net/docs/ormlite/ormlite-overview).

So I've created a small class which represents the attachment in the database:

```cs
public class Attachment {
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public byte[] Data { get; set; }
}
```

And here is the actual file

```cs
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(webclient.DownloadData(...));
byte[] data = new byte[...];
ms.Read(data, 0, data.Length);

Attachment file = new Attachment() {
    /* all the other stuff */
    Data = data
};
```

No problems until now... :)

Now I have all I need to put this file into database. So lets get it on...

```cs
dbCmd.Insert<Attachment>(file);
```

And there is the problem...

```
SqlException: "Operand type clash: text is incompatible with image"
```

ORMlite transforms the byte array into a base64 encoded string

```sql
/* stripped-down example of the command string */
INSERT INTO Attachment (Data) VALUES ('CgoKCgoKCjxodG1sPgo8a...AAAA==')
```

I've searched all day long but did not find a solution to change the way ORMlite handles `byte[]` arrays. There is no attribute `DatabaseField` which I could use to set the `dataType` to `BYTE_ARRAY` as it is possible in Java.

```java
@DatabaseField(dataType = DataType.BYTE_ARRAY)
byte[] imageBytes;
```

Have I missed something essential?
Is there another way of getting the file into the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ServiceStack.OrmLite v4, as specified by mythz in the comments, everything should work as-is.

---

In v3, if you want to have byte arrays serialized as binary instead of base 64 strings, you should inherit from `SqliteOrmLiteDialectProvider` and override the functions responsible for converting CLR values from and to SQL values to handle byte arrays.

```
public class ByteArrayAwareSqliteOrmLiteDialectProvider
    : SqliteOrmLiteDialectProvider {

    public override object ConvertDbValue(object value, Type type) {
        var bytes = value as byte[];
        if (bytes != null && type == typeof(byte[]))
            return bytes;

        return base.ConvertDbValue(value, type);
    }

    public override string GetQuotedValue(object value, Type fieldType) {
        var bytes = value as byte[];
        if (bytes != null && fieldType == typeof(byte[]))
            return "X'" + BitConverter.ToString(data).Replace("-", "") + "'";

        return base.GetQuotedValue(value, fieldType);
    }

}
```

Then, configure your dialect provider properly:

```
OrmLiteConfig.DialectProvider = new ByteArrayAwareSqliteOrmLiteDialectProvider();
```

Comment: It should work by default so you shouldn't have to do this, I've just [added a working test for this to confirm](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/commit/fb608c05323a0d4a75fbe2433cfb170be6844083).

Comment: @mythz By default (at least in latest v3) it serializes the bytes as a base64 string. Sure, the test passes, but there is unnecessary overhead a larger database size.

Comment: Saying you **must inherit** is incorrect. In v4 it uses parameterized queries which is saved as **byte[]** in the ADO.NET provider. Whilst in v3 uses base64, which you should at least clarify. Recommending to use a custom DialectProvider is not a solution to be recommended lightly.

Comment: @mythz Sorry, I have no experience with SS v4 (we're considering buying a commercial license for start-ups if we have to upgrade, but v3 is sufficient for now - great work btw) and this was the only solution in v3.I have edited my post to take your remarks into account. Feel free to edit it further if needed :)

Answer (score 5):

So I think you are confused between the [ORMLite inside of ServiceStack](http://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite) and [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/) the Java ORM library -- they are not related nor necessary compatible.

What you may be asking is how to read data that was written by the Java ORMLite using the C# ORMLite.  I'm not experienced with the C# side at all but I can talk about what ORMLite is doing here:

```
@DatabaseField(dataType = DataType.BYTE_ARRAY)
byte[] imageBytes;
```

In SqlServer, this should correspond to the field:

```
"bytes" IMAGE
```

The SQL insert command that is passed to JDBC is:

```
 INSERT INTO "bytearray" ("bytes" ) VALUES (?)
 insert arguments: [[B@34883357] (byte[])
```

It retrieves the `byte[]` from the results with a `results.getBytes(columnPos)`.

You mention:

> ORMlite transforms the byte array into a base64 encoded string

This is JDBC doing this.  I'm surprised that it does but I guess it is possible.

Hope something in here helps.

Comment: I'm aware of the two different versions :) And no I'm not asking "how to read data that was written by the Java ORMlite" as I'm the only one who writes data to the database with the non-java version - or at least I would if there wasn't this problem^^ I've just mentioned the Java version as I would be able to define the column type by hand and I'm missing this option in the .Net version.

Comment: There's no reason to apologize @Gray - I'm thankful for every info I can get :)

Answer (score 0):

For Oracle provider, I forked 3.9.71 of the oracle provider since I needed to use the ODP.NET libraries (Oracle.DataAcess) as my project was doing some UDT work, and needed the UDTType object on the OracleParameter objects. Also, I was inserting a compressed proprietary "xml like" string as byte array to a BLOB column.

In my project, I used

```
public class OracleOrmLiteDialectProvider : OrmLiteDialectProviderBase<OracleOrmLiteDialectProvider>
... 
    public override string GetQuotedValue(object value, Type fieldType)
    {
... 
        if (fieldType == typeof(byte[]))
        {
            var bytes = value as byte[];
            return "to_blob (utl_raw.cast_to_raw('" + Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes)+ "'))";
        }
...
}
```

The better solution of course is to get it planned for budget next year and go to 4.0.